# Boolean Geometry Help

Tags: mechanical-engineering, geometry

I just don't get the concept of Boolean Geometry... Can you help me understand how to solve these homework problems? 
Thanks!

[image: HomeworkProblems]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: @Wasabi oops! Just saw this. I will remember for next time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Boolean" just means logically true or false. For this exercise you have to figure out which edges exist when the parts intersect or cut.

[image]

*Figure 1. Partial completion of exercise 1.*

Exercise 1 requires you to create the combined solid consisting of A and B but with a cutout C. This means that you have the box and wedge combined and a hole cut through with shape C.

I've drawn in a few edges for you to get you started. Note that the top edge of the box has a gap in it where the wedge juts through. If you were to run your finger across the left face you would feel no edge there.

Can you continue from there?

Note that the **∩** symbol is the 'intersect' operation as used in set theory. The result of that boolean operation will be the parts that are common to both objects when merged.

It might be nice to use a different colour to darken the 'hidden' edges - those you can't see from the chosen viewing angle.

Comment: Thanks! I have about 5 pages of this stuff left, so I'm sure I'll fully understand by the time I'm through haha

Comment: It's interesting that the exercise allows the student to use 3D modeling software to create the results. It would certainly make visualization easier. With the figures provided, it would be easy enough to generate a clean, quick OpenSCAD file, but it would be surprising if that was the referenced software.

Comment: There is no exercise 5 in the image. "Primatives?" The teacher needs to have his work proofread. My OpenSCAD home-exercise went well. A fun task, I hope the OP experiences success.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Woah... I didn't even notice the problem was missing! Yeah, he's not the greatest Prof haha Thanks for the good wishes!